# Using the Sherman-Morrison to find the inverse of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

PS: I don't know how to reduce the size of the second matrix below so that it fits in the page, someone please help

I'm reading the paper [Beyond Homophily in Graph Neural Networks: Current Limitations and Effective Designs](https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.11468) by Zhu et. al. In one of their proofs, the authors mention the following:

$[(A+I)X]_{T_{S,:}} = \begin{bmatrix}
hd +1 & \frac{1-h}{|Y|-1}d & \frac{1-h}{|Y|-1}d & \dots & \frac{1-h}{|Y|-1}d\\
\frac{1-h}{|Y|-1}d & hd +1 & \frac{1-h}{|Y|-1}d & \dots & \frac{1-h}{|Y|-1}d\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
\frac{1-h}{|Y|-1}d & \frac{1-h}{|Y|-1}d & \dots & \frac{1-h}{|Y|-1}d & hd +1\\
\end{bmatrix}_{|Y|\times|Y|}$

Note that $[(A+I)X]_{T_{S,:}}$ is a circulant matrix, therefore its inverse exists.  Using the Sherman-Morrison formula, we can find its inverse as:

$([(A+I)X]_{T_{S,:}})^{-1} = \frac{1}{(d+1)(|Y|-1+(|Y|h-1)d)}\begin{bmatrix}
(|Y|−1) + (|Y|−2 +h)d & (h-1)d & (h-1)d & \dots & (h-1)d\\
(h-1)d & (|Y|−1) + (|Y|−2 +h)d & (h-1)d & \dots & (h-1)d\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
(h-1)d & (h-1)d & \dots & (h-1)d & (|Y|−1) + (|Y|−2 +h)d\\
\end{bmatrix}_{|Y|\times|Y|}$

I don't quite understand how they got this from the Sherman-Morrison formula, which according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman%E2%80%93Morrison_formula):

"Suppose $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is an invertible square matrix and $u,v\in\mathbb{R}^n$ are column vectors. Then $A + uv^\textsf{T}$ is invertible iff $1 + v^\textsf{T} A^{-1}u \neq 0$. In this case,
$\left(A + uv^\textsf{T}\right)^{-1} = A^{-1} - {A^{-1}uv^\textsf{T}A^{-1} \over 1 + v^\textsf{T}A^{-1}u}$"

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodbury_matrix_identity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For applying the Sherman-Morrison formula to calculate the inverse of the matrix you mentioned, $\mathbf{A}, \mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{v}$ in the formula can be set as
$$
\mathbf{A} = \left((hd+1)-\frac{(1-h)}{|Y|-1}d\right)\mathbf{I}_{|Y|} = \frac{d (h |Y|-1)+|Y|-1}{|Y|-1}\;\mathbf{I}_{|Y|}
$$
$$
\mathbf{u} = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & \cdots & 1
\end{bmatrix}_{|Y|}^{\textsf{T}}
$$
$$
\mathbf{v} = \frac{(1-h)}{|Y|-1}d \cdot \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & \cdots & 1
\end{bmatrix}_{|Y|}
$$
From here the inverse of the matrix can be obtained by a straightforward application of the formula.